# CSS holy grail - issue with 2 fixed / 1 fluid column

Tags: html, css

Okay so I have been working on implementing the 'holy grail'-style layout for my website, so far it's pretty close but I noticed two things I want to fix.

The goal is a 'sticky' footer with the page length expands with the browser window height, a header, and 3 columns. 2 fixed columns on the left and right side, and a fluid column in the middle.

The issues I am having are that right now, my center 'fluid' column doesn't seem to be acting like I expected. Basically I want the fixed columns to always be fully shown, with the center column filling the remaining horizontal space. But the center column is taking up a lot of room and making it so that I have to scroll to view the right column (see image below). Also, the 'text-align: center' code doesn't appear to be centering text within the viewable area of the center column. Any help appreciated!

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKU0g.png

html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <p>Header</p>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="center">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div id="left">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    background: #5D7B93;
    height: 95px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 15;
}
#center{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 105px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#left {

    height: 100%;   
    width: 150px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#EAEAEA;
    margin-top: 105px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: -100%;
    margin-top: 105px;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
#footer {
    text-align:center;
    background: #5D7B93;
    height:25px;
    padding:5px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I went a different route using positioning: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/ANZct/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to `float`. Just `position: absolute` the sidebars and give the center div fixed margin on both sides.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvaCp/1/)

**CSS**

```
#container{
    position: relative;
}

#left, #right {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#left {
    left: 0;
}

#right {
    right: 0;
}

#center {
    margin: 0 200px;
}
```

Comment: @Caleb : I'd go with this implementation if you can

Answer (score 0):

i've done this on my layout and it works fine for me

```
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
}

#left {
  width: 240px!important;
  min-width: 240px!important;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  width: 400px!important;
  min-width: 400px!important;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

#center {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}
```